# Slide div from left to right, but not from the left side of the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to slide in some text from left to right, but I need it to be in the middle of the page. When I say middle, it is because this will slide from the left side of the page. Basically when I hover an element, I need it to display text next to it, but it has to slide in.

http://jsfiddle.net/do1wx8p8/

```
$("strong").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $("#nope").show("slide", { 
        direction: "left"
    }, 200);
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $("#nope").hide("slide", { 
        direction: "left"
    }, 200);
});
```

This works perfectly, but since it's a div, it will change it to `display: block`, which forces it down to the next line. What do I have to do, to make it slide in right after that colon? I basically want it to slide in from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

All in one line. Help appreciated!

Comment: CSS can do this http://jsfiddle.net/do1wx8p8/1/ but first of all, generate valid and coherent html. then , when you use jQuery function , make sure you understand what css rules are implied or write your own to be in control ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus I appreciate it, but look how the text is behind the text. I knew how to do that already, but the text slides behind the text. I basically need it to slide in from right after the colon, not at the left side of the page, as written in the question. If the "Text here:" was placed in the middle of the page, it would fly in from the left. See where I'm getting? ;)

Comment: Oh, and if the background color had a different color. Small fix but it's more a fix than a solution :)

Comment: there is many css options, i should have pointed out more clearly that your html is insane and tha you should mind it ( you'll find out by yourself ) ;) , then the use of js here might not be  needed. (just comments, not an answer ;) )

Comment: @GCyrillus How is my HTML insane? Please elaborate, because you clearly showed you do insane fixes instead of solving them completely.

Comment: see https://validator.w3.org/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML .;) you just clearly misunderstood the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a few other CSS properties to achieve this. I added the following:

```
#nope {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
     float: left;

}
#rolloverme {
    display: block;
     float: left;
}


<strong id="rolloverme">Text here: </strong>
<div id="nope" >Sliding text</div>
```

The key is making the element float. This pulls it out of the regular box model positioning. 
https://jsfiddle.net/do1wx8p8/

Comment: Oh yeah this is definitely the one I am looking for. Thanks a lot, dude!

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the dynamic element in another div that has inline block display property.

HTML:

```
<div class="text">
    <strong>Text here: </strong>
</div>
<div id="nope" class="text"><span>Sliding text</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
    display: inline-block;    
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

See this fiddle (yours but updated)

http://jsfiddle.net/5wy0gw8a/

Good luck :)

Comment: Might want to update that link to the correct one ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar example for you,just the transition timing is different but you will get the idea of it

```
<div class="holdingbox">
  <span class="leftbox">Slide text</span>
  <span class="rightbox">
   <span class="content">Slide text here</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is the `css` code, there are some flaws in it as i am not so good with transition.

```
.rightbox {
position: relative;
display:inline-block;
overflow:hidden;
height:30px;
vertical-align:top;
}
.content{
width:100px;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}
```

And the jquery i got from some website for `animate`

```
$('.leftbox').hover(function(){
   $('.rightbox').animate({width: '90px'}, 1000)
   }, function(){
   $('.rightbox').animate({width: '0'}, 1000)
});
```

Comment: That actually works better than expected. However, the width kinda bugs me. The sliding content ("Slide text here" in your case) is dynamic and I don't know the width of it.